# Using a predicate to search through a string - Scala

Tags: scala, predicate

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to search through a string with a given predicate and determining its position in the string.

> def find(x: Char => Boolean): Boolean = {
>
> }

Example, if x is (_ == ' ')

String = "hi my name is"

It would add 2 to the counter and return true

Comment: Isn't what you want to do the same as just using `"hi my name is".indexOf(' ')`, if you want a boolean then check if the answer is >= 0?

Comment: Could you provide some more detail?  What is this counter you mention?  There is already a method on string `indexOf` which will return the first index of a character, what do you need that this doesn't give you?

Comment: @DennisHunziker I already have a function written how you've mentioned but this is supposed to perform the same task but this time with a predicate as the parameter

Comment: @puhlen the counter just points first index of that character

Comment: @Ye.Doe Which counter?

Comment: Return a boolean, a position, a counter - do you really know what you want? :)

Comment: It would add 2 to the counter as it points to the first space ("hi my name is"). Not really I'm losing my mind help

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this is what you want...

Since `find` is a *higher-order function* (*HOF*) - that is, it's a function that takes a function as an argument - it likely needs to be applied to a `String` instance. The *predicate* (the function argument to `find`) determines when the character you're looking for is found, and the `find` method reports the position at which the character was found. So `find` should return an `Option[Int]`, not a `Boolean`, that way you don't lose the information about where the character was found. Note that you can still change an `Option[Int]` result to a `Boolean` value (with `true` indicating the search was successful, `false` not) by applying `.isDefined` to the result.

Note that I've renamed `find` to `myFind` to avoid a clash with the built-in `String.find` method (which does a similar job).

```scala
import scala.annotation.tailrec

// Implicit class cannot be a top-level element, so it's put in an object.
object StringUtils {

  // "Decorate" strings with additional functions.
  final implicit class MyRichString(val s: String)
  extends AnyVal {

    // Find a character satisfying predicate p, report position.
    def myFind(p: Char => Boolean): Option[Int] = {

      // Helper function to keep track of current position.
      @tailrec
      def currentPos(pos: Int): Option[Int] = {

        // If we've passed the end of the string, return None. Didn't find a
        // character satisfying predicate.
        if(pos >= s.length) None

        // Otherwise, if the predicate passes for the current character,
        // return position wrapped in Some.
        else if(p(s(pos))) Some(pos)

        // Otherwise, perform another iteration, looking at the next character.
        else currentPos(pos + 1)
      }

      // Start by looking at the first (0th) character.
      currentPos(0)
    }
  }
}

import StringUtils._
val myString = "hi my name is"
myString.myFind(_ == ' ') // Should report Some(2)
myString.myFind(_ == ' ').isDefined // Should report true
myString.myFind(_ == 'X') // Should report None
myString.myFind(_ == 'X').isDefined // Should report false
```

If the use of an implicit class is a little too much effort, you could implement this as a single function that takes the `String` as an argument:

```scala
def find(s: String, p: Char => Boolean): Option[Int] = {

  // Helper function to keep track of current position.
  @tailrec
  def currentPos(pos: Int): Option[Int] = {

    // If we've passed the end of the string, return None. Didn't find a
    // character satisfying predicate.
    if(pos >= s.length) None

    // Otherwise, if the predicate passes for the current character,
    // return position wrapped in Some.
    else if(p(s(pos))) Some(pos)

    // Otherwise, perform another iteration, looking at the next character.
    else currentPos(pos + 1)
  }

  // Start by looking at the first (0th) character.
  currentPos(0)
}

val myString = "hi my name is"
find(myString, _ == ' ') // Should report Some(2)
find(myString, _ == ' ').isDefined // Should report true
find(myString, _ == 'X') // Should report None
find(myString, _ == 'X').isDefined // Should report false
```

Answer (score 0):

Counter:

```
"hi my name is".count (_ == 'm')

"hi my name is".toList.filter (_ == 'i').size
```

Boolean:

```
"hi my name is".toList.exists (_ == 'i')

"hi my name is".contains ('j')
```

Position(s):

```
"hi my name is".zipWithIndex.filter {case (a, b) => a == 'i'}
res8: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Char, Int)] = Vector((i,1), (i,11))
```

Usage of find:

```
scala> "hi my name is".find (_ == 'x') 
res27: Option[Char] = None

scala> "hi my name is".find (_ == 's') 
res28: Option[Char] = Some(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest separating the character `search` and `position` into individual methods, each of which leverages built-in functions in `String`, and wrap in an `implicit class`:

```
object MyStringOps {
  implicit class CharInString(s: String) {

    def charPos(c: Char): Int = s.indexOf(c)

    def charFind(p: Char => Boolean): Boolean =
      s.find(p) match {
        case Some(_) => true
        case None => false
      }
  }
}

import MyStringOps._

"hi my name is".charPos(' ')
// res1: Int = 2

"hi my name is".charFind(_ == ' ')
// res2: Boolean = true
```